# Update existing unique keys columns in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in that i have unique key .Now because of some reasons i want to update the unique key. AS of now unique key is having 4 columns now i want to add 2 more columns in that

```
 CREATE TABLE abc (
  id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  one varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  search_id varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  session_id varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  pnr varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  origin varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  destination varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  type varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  name1 varchar(55) NOT NULL,
  name2 varchar(55) NOT NULL,
  number varchar(55) DEFAULT '',
  text text,
  cr_dt timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
   UNIQUE KEY aedi_id (one,search_id,session_id,origin,destination,pnr,number) //I have this
  UNIQUE KEY aedi_id (one,search_id,session_id,origin,destination,pnr,name1,name2,number) I want this 
)
```

Comment: use `alter` to *drop* defined `key` and re-alter to add new definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is:

```
alter table drop key aedi_id;

alter table add key aedi_id (one, search_id, session_id, origin, destination, pnr, name1, name2, number) ;
```

Note that a unique key is implemented as an index, which will be used for queries.  This means that the order of the columns matters in the key definition -- some orderings will work better for your queries.  So, depending on your queries, you may want to re-arrange the columns.